# invalid command name in TCL

Tags: tcl

invalid command name "if{0}{"

[image: tcl script output]

[image: tcl script]

Giving me an error, for that I have find how many cell in the file.
Where am I making a mistake?

Update::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I am having an issue while sorting an array...
It says
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imJmh.png)

Since the last element is integer, still it says "expected integer but got...
Where am i making mistake?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In ordear to make things easier for other users, please type your code inside the question with proper formatting instead of linking images containing code

Answer (score 4):

You must place a space between 'if' and the opening brace.
Basicly, the Tcl interpreter tokenizes commands by searching for whitespace, while at the same time substituting stuff inside []. So first, the regexpr is evaluated, yieling 0 and togehter with the remaining characters this yields the command name.

Comment: @CLEX420, You'll want to read the [Tcl syntax documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) a couple of times. You are clashing with rule #3.